# Tomcat 9 redirection from iis 10

Tags: windows-10, iis-10, tomcat9

I have configured  tomcat 9 and iis10 in my system(windows 10) , using the below link
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Configurations has been double checked .

The error is 
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\PROJECT\Tomcat\bin\isapi_redirect.dll" failed.

If i am enabling 32 bit application  true..I am getting error 404 not found.
If I am disabling 32 bit  , i am getting the above error.

In the logs , the isapi_redirect log is not getting created also.

Please help in fixing, as I am not getting what is the mistake I am doing.

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft only supports you to run Tomcat via HttpPlatformHandler, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manjug/2015/11/27/understanding-iis-httpplatformhandler-using-tomcat-8/

Comment: try to check that dll is available at the right place and the name is correct. try to set the permission of iis user to access the dll. you could refer this [link](https://forums.iis.net/post/1893075.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: After doing some more googling and r&d changes, now the error obatined is HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error Detailed Error Information:
Module    IsapiFilterModule
Notification    AuthenticateRequest
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code    0x80070001
Requested URL    http://localhost:80/
Physical Path    C:\ASDAPP\Webapp
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory    C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles. Gave permission to  users ,iusrs, mycurrentapppool etc..but nothing is working.

Comment: did you assign iis users permissions to the Webapp folder? and under which identity your application pool is running?